# Can I create a pointer to an object in the constructor of said object?

Tags: c++, object, pointers

The goal is that every time I create an object of my Car class, a pointer of this object is then created and placed in the "car registry".

This is what I have:

```
class Car {
private:
    string color = "blah blah";
    string make = "blah blah";
    string model = "blah blah";
public:
    Car(CarRegisterManager* carRegisterManager) {
        // This is where I want to "register" any object of this class with a pointer
        // to reference of this created object inserted into the CarRegisterManager's vector or 
        // registered cars.
        carRegisterManager->registerCar( /*pointer goes here*/ );
    }
}

class CarRegisterManager {
private:
    std::vector<Car> registeredCars_;
public:
    void registerCar(Car* car) {
        registeredCars_.push_back(car);
    }
}

int main() {

     CarRegisterManager carRegisterManager;
     CarRegisterManager* p_carRegisterManager = &carRegisterManager;
     Car hondaCivic1(p_carRegisterManager); // When this is created, I want a pointer to it registered.    

}
```

As you can see, part of my solution was to upon creation of the CarRegisterManager to create a pointer to the manager object to include as a parameter in the constructor of any Car object, then having the constructor do something with that. I know I need to use a "this" or something to indicate that this created Car object needs a pointer created for it, and then this pointer is put into the CarRegisterManager's registerCar function.

I'm still struggling with the concept of using keywords new and this, if that is indeed what I would need to use here. I apologize if this is answered somewhere else. I legitimately searched for a while before posting this. I may not be using the correct key terms to set these things up.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "pointer-to-reference"? A reference is, roughly speaking, an *alias* for an object instance. So a pointer to that is the same as a pointer to the referenced object. You cannot form a pointer to the reference itself.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Sorry I was misusing a term I had heard. I simply mean I want to have a pointer created of an object in the creation/constructor of said object. I've updated the title to reflect such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know the answer, because you state it in your question:

> **I know I need to use a "this" or something** to indicate that this created Car object needs a pointer created for it, and then this pointer is put into the CarRegisterManager's registerCar function.

You can use the *literal* `this` pointer, eg:

```cpp
Car(CarRegisterManager* carRegisterManager) {
    carRegisterManager->registerCar(this);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Remy. I appreciate the response.